# How do I get 100% height for this element?

Tags: css

I want the left-div height to be 100% that of window.

```
<div id="left-div"></div>

    <div id="content">

        <div class="thumbnail"></div>
        <div class="thumbnail"></div>
        <div class="thumbnail"></div>
        <div class="thumbnail"></div>
        <div class="thumbnail"></div>
        <div class="thumbnail"></div>
        <div class="thumbnail"></div>
        <div class="thumbnail"></div>   
        <div class="thumbnail"></div>
        <div class="thumbnail"></div>
        <div class="thumbnail"></div>
        <div class="thumbnail"></div>   
        <div class="thumbnail"></div>
        <div class="thumbnail"></div>
        <div class="thumbnail"></div>
        <div class="thumbnail"></div>

    </div>
```

here is the full code :
http://jsfiddle.net/Fs6yE/

I've already applied backgrounds for both html and body tags.So that is out of the question.
Is there any other way?

Comment: You want the rainbow bar to go all the way to the bottom?  Do you want it to stretch the image or repeat the image?

Comment: That's exactly what I want!

Comment: Which is it, stretch or repeat?

Comment: I want it to repeat-y

Comment: $("#left-div").css("height",$(document).height()+'px'); just add this

Comment: I already got an answer but Thank You Nirus! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do it how you have it structured is to use jQuery. The method below will allow it to be resized

```
    function myResize() {
            $('#left-div').height($('#content').outerHeight());
        };

        myResize();

        $(window).load(function(){
            myResize();
        });


        $(window).resize(function() {
            myResize();
        });
```

ADD CSS TO #content

```
overflow: hidden;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9Hq6c/

Other methods involve making both elements children of the same parent and have a specified height on the parent, or some css hacks with backgrounds under the #content element.

Comment: I tried your jquery method.It doesn't work!
http://i.imgur.com/iy9Ghzz.jpg

the  left-div 's height becomes 0px!?

Comment: oops forget to include the css. check now

Answer (score 0):

Add `margin: 0;` to your `body` CSS, like this:

```
body {
  background:#FCFCFC;
  margin: 0;
}
```

**[See updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fs6yE/4/)**

Comment: I want the left-div 's height to be 100%.Your code doesn't fix it!

Answer (score 0):

When you set an element to 100%, always think "100% of what?". It's always the parent of that element. In your case, the parent element is the body and it is not set to anything. So set it to 100% height.

But then ask yourself, 100% of what? The body's parent is the html element. So set that to a height of 100%, too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change a few css items to get this to work.

First, the `thumbnail` class needs to remove `float:left`.  Replace the `float` with `display:inline-block`.  The reason you do this is because float takes away from the height of the body container.  So instead of `body` being 2000px high, it's only 200.

Next, add `position:relative` to the `body` tags css.  You have the `left-div` as `position:absolute`.  Absolute positioning is relative to another container, and by adding the css to the body tag you're saying that the `left-div` should be absolutely positioned within the `body` tag.

Lastly, add `background-repeat:repeat-y` to the `left-div` css.  Here is an [UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/K6mNu/10/) with my changes.